# Ruby returns TypeError when trying to require a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec2

I have a table called Courses with two columns `dept_code` and `course_code` that are both strings.

I am writing my specs and I want to call the following module so I can use the `valid_course_attributes` method to assign attributes to `@course`.

```
module CoursesSpecHelper

  def valid_course_attributes
    {
     :dept_code => 'HIST',
     :course_code => '1010'
    }
  end

end
```

The module is called as such:

```
describe Courses do
  require CoursesSpecHelper

  before(:each) do
    @course = Courses.new
  end

  it "should require dept_code" do
    @course.attributes = valid_course_attributes.except(:dept_code)
    @course.should have(1).error_on(:dept_code)
  end

end
```

When I run my examples, I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: can't convert Module into String
```

I have tried a couple of variations, but I cannot figure out what this problem means.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want

```
include CoursesSpecHelper
```